# Validating Zip Code using Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I am writing a function in pl/sql to validate zip code. The validation condition is that it should accept only 4 digit number and null as valid code. Below is what i have written:

```
create or replace function is_valid_zip( p_zip_code in varchar2 )
return boolean
is
begin
           if (length(trim(p_zip_code)))<>4
           then return false;
           elsif (owa_pattern.match(p_zip_code,'\b\d{4}\b'))
           then return true;
           elsif (p_zip_code is null)
           then return true;
           else
           return false;
           end if;
end;
```

The above code is accepting '!234' as a valid code. I am not sure where i am wrong.Can anybody point out the mistake in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex:

```
^null$|^\d{4}$
```

You are using `\b` to mark boundaries. As your input would be only `1234` or `null` or like that, you can simply use start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors.

Regex Decomposition:

1. `^null$` - `null` only.
2. `|` - Or.
3. `^\d{4}$` - Four digit string like `1234`.

**[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jF2pW6)**

Comment: but howcome "!234" is being matched using "\b\d{4}\b" regex? I mean d{4} should match 4 digits in the string right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gaurang. Its working fine on the online link but when i replaced it in the code , it is showing '1234' as invalid.                                                        elsif (owa_pattern.match(p_zip_code,'^null$|^\d{4}$'))
   then return true;

Comment: @Esha - can you please give the exact line of code you modified? Thanks!

Comment: @GaurangTandon - The online tools you're using do not use pl/sql's regex engine. As you said, it IS working but the problem is that it doesn't seem to work using Oracle PL/SQL. Now, I don't have that software so I can't test.

Comment: @KumarVaibhav Neither do I have the software.

Comment: ya I guess this is some pl/sql related anomaly.

Comment: @Gaurang- I made some changes and applied your expression. Its working fine now. thanks again :)